# Pip Package Installation Error

Tags: python, pip

When I try to install a package called semidbm using Pip, I get the following error message.

http://gyazo.com/e0aefbf81a044f25ac720130602a9a01

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I forgot to mention im using Windows 7 32 bit

Comment: what is the version of your python?

Comment: Please add the error log to your question. Images are not indexed. It is nearly impossible for others with a similar problem to find your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Python 3.1.

The [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html#python-os-support) says:

> pip works with CPython versions 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4 and also pypy.

So there is no support for Python 3.1

It's wiser anyway to upgrade your Python version to, say, 3.4. There's a bunch of packages that don't support Python 3.0 or 3.1, and 3.4 simply brings extra goodies (without being backwards incompatible in the Python 3.x series).

Comment: Oh dear, that was stupid of me. Thanks for pointing that out for me :P

Comment: @Tardistom if this answer helped solve your problem, please click the check mark next to it to indicate that it is [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).